# Surprised by output

Tags: c++, pointers

Compiled and ran the code below and was surprised by the output.

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char* c="hello";

    for (size_t i=0; i<116; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *(c+i);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hellobasic_stringallocator<T>::allocate(size_t n) 'n' exceeds maximum supported sizeSt16nested_exception
```

Is this just undefined behavior or something else?

Comment: accessing beyond allocated memory is UB. This happens when i >= 6

Comment: What did you expect? You said you were surpised, that means you had some other expectations.

Comment: @al3c I was expecting some gibberish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something else: bad code leading to a buffer overflow. Your `c` has exactly 6 bytes allocated in the read only section it points to, yet you're trying to read past its end, which then triggers a look up for the first `'\0'` character.

Luckily for you, that character is so far away from the beginning of the string (`c + 6`) that the string allocator gives up.

Comment: String allocator doesn't seem doing anything special. The message should be just happened to be after the string `hello`.

Comment: He's probably running it in debug mode, which triggers the STL to make a `string` out of the pointer perhaps? I'd hope the release build skips the memory allocation and copy!